# Parsing tab delimited file with double quotes in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, csv, perl-module, text-parsing

I have a data set that is tab delimited with the user-agent strings in double quotes. I need to parse each of these columns and based on the answer of my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500407/in-perl-how-can-i-correctly-parse-tab-space-delimited-files-with-quoted-strings) I used the Text::CSV module.

```
94410634  0   GET  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; AskTB5.5)"   1
```

The code is a simple one.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new(sep_char => "\t");

    while (<>) {
        if ($csv->parse($_)) {
            my @columns = $csv->fields();
            print "@columns\n";
        } else {
            my $err = $csv->error_input;
            print "Failed to parse line: $err";
        }
    }
```

But i get the `Failed to parse line:` error when I try it on this dataset. what am I doing wrong? I need to extract the 4th column containing the user-agent strings for further processing.

Comment: Are you sure those are tabs, not spaces? Using *' '* as sep_char like this *my $csv = Text::CSV->new({sep_char => ' '});* (also note the {}s around the options) works (though it makes the useragent field the 8th field).

Comment: @MKV - I am pretty sure SO formatting removed the tabs - in my answer I explicitly re-built the string to be tab-separated for that reason

Comment: @DVK Spaces would explain OP's error though.

Comment: @MkV the files are tab separated, as @DVK said it doesn't look like that because of SO formatting. My problems may lie in the perl module installation itself though and I am looking into it.

Comment: @marcog - quite possible, though I don't understand how the tabs would be lost in the actual log file. May be the data was already somehow munged?

Comment: @sfactor - are you on Unix or Windows? On unix, please run this: `cat  -vet my_log_file_name | head -3` and check whether the output has spaces or "`^I`" sequences where you expect tabs. `cat -vet` prints out all the special chacters as special printable sequences (TAB=>^I, newline => $, etc...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your constructor arguments should be in a hashref, not a hash:

   my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { sep_char => "\t" } );
2. Are you sure the dataset is exactly what you think it is? May be there's a double quote missing somewhere or there were no tabs?

   To verify the file contents, are you on Unix/Linux or Windows? On unix, please run this: `cat -vet my_log_file_name | head -3` and check whether the output has spaces or "^I" sequences where you expect tabs. `cat -vet` prints out all the special characters as special printable sequences (`TAB` => `^I`, newline => `$`, etc...)

The following test works perfectly on my ActivePerl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $s = qq[94410634\t0\tGET\t"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; AskTB5.5)"\t1\n];;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({sep_char => "\t"});

if ($csv->parse($s)) {
    my @columns = $csv->fields();
    print "c=$columns[3]\n";
} else {
    my $err = $csv->error_input;
    print "Failed to parse line: $err";
}
```

**Output**:

```
C:\> perl d:\scripts\test4.pl
c=Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; ...
```

Comment: Eish, point 1 means my [+17 answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4500407/in-perl-how-can-i-correctly-parse-tab-space-delimited-files-with-quoted-strings/4500478#4500478) has an error. I better fix that!

Comment: The problem may be with the Text::CSV module installed in the server. I am checking up on that as well because I still get the error. Time to see the system admin I guess :).

Comment: @marcog - great - and the 17 upvoters and 17+N viewers (myself included) didn't notice. So much for famous collective SO wisdom :)

Comment: yes it was a problem with the prel module somehow it was not installed correctly in the server, but again it should have been hashref as well. thanks.